# Error 503 when initializing the AEM 6.5.0 instance

Tags: aem, aem-6

[image]
I am facing 503 AuthenticationSupport service missing. Cannot authenticate request error every time server is started. This happened many times. There is no such broken error information on the error log file. I have even deleted the repository but didn't help much. I even use oak but still no use. I had set up it multiple times to skip this error but I don't feel confident with this approach. For better information, I am attaching the latest error log file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXEcZP_Tvk1ebBxfOmR9Q1ffk2KLeW66/view?usp=sharing

NOTE: I am a beginner in AEM. Please be gentle

java -Xmx6000m -jar oak-run-1.8.0.jar check --bin=-1 C:\Users\mahinder.singh\Documents\Projects\Adobe\author\crx-quickstart\repository\segmentstore

Comment: Oak Run usually is not enough for this, the error.log is no longer accessible, but I would recommend to make sure to use the proper oak-run. AEM 6.5.0 uses a higher oak version, it is better to use the version that matches the AEM repository version.

Answer (score -1):

This is usual. Might be taking a little longer time than usual to load. Wait for a while.

If the issue still persists reinstall the instance and allow the aem to get kicked up on it's own.